# TaskCancelation Exception on HTTP Request using callback async model?

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making some http request on windows phone 8.1, some times when the request is made its return this exception

```
TaskCanceledException A task was canceled
```

I don't know if this is a cause of this issue but I'm not using a Task Based Async model ( those `await` and `async` ) I'm using a simple callback model like

```
public void method(){
    makeRequest(delegate(Custom Object){
        //doing something
    });
}

public void makeRequest(Action<Custom Object> callback){
    //make the request

    //invoice callback
    callback(new object);
}
```

Comment: On Win 8.1 / Phone 8.1, an http request is sent as an async operation - by default. Async operations are sometimes associated with Task and sometimes not - 'hint' is the operative word. Where an exception in an async environment occurs is often not that obvious and requires some digging around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could be fired up if you got the timeout during your http request.
[Related discussion on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/47a086ab-7e0e-450b-b79e-d04a1037220a/how-to-eliminate-a-task-was-canceled-taskcanceledexception-while-using-httpclient-?forum=winappswithcsharp).

If you are sending requests on regular basis, try to fire up another one if you got this exception.

Comment: I did that work around, I'm making another request when I got this exception but it throw another one with the same type.

Comment: Do you ask server for a long file?

Comment: I got a timeout of 2 - minutes and I'm testing from another client and its working.

Comment: It was a timeout errror, I miss a param, the timeout was about 2 segs :/ btw thanks.